# Including matplotlib figure() messes up Tkinter Checkbuttons()

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm writing a Tkinter gui, also using matplotlib figures. Since I switched from a Canopy Python 2.7 distribution to a manual installed Python 2.7 installation I encounter wired problems with Tkinter checkbuttons. One can use the buttons but the variable is not set. The problem only appears when I include a matplotlib figure (see example code, 1st lin in main()).

Win7-64

Working installation:
Enthought Canopy 1.7.4.3348, 
Python 2.7.11, 
matplotlib 2.0.0-8

Now (not working): 
Python 2.7.16, 
matplotlib 2.2.4

```py
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk as ttk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, gui_master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, gui_master)
        self.gui_master = gui_master
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.gui_master)
        self.frame.grid()
        self.var = tk.IntVar()
        check_STD = ttk.Checkbutton(self.frame, variable= self.var, command = self.check_select)
        check_STD.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

    def check_select(self):
        print 'var', self.var, self.var.get()

def main():
    rp_fig, rp_ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize = (9,9))
    gui_root = tk.Tk()
    gui_root.title("FXD-CSD-GUI")
    app = Application(gui_master=gui_root)
    gui_root.mainloop()
    plt.show()

main()
```

Comment: using ```rp_fig = plt.Figure(figsize=(9, 9))
rp_ax = rp_fig.add_subplot(111)``` it works but I don't get why...

Comment: `plt.show()` blocks the excution of any further code. When using `matplotlib.figure.Figure()` instead of `plt.figure()` you are not using pyplot, hence `plt.show()` has no figure to show  and hence will not block.